# CancellationToken not working with WaitForConnectionAsync

Tags: c#, asynchronous, named-pipes

```
NamedPipeServerStream server=new NamedPipeServerStream("aaqq");
var ct=new CancellationTokenSource();
ct.CancelAfter(1000);
server.WaitForConnectionAsync(ct.Token).Wait();
```

I would expect the last line to throw an `OperationCanceledException` after a second, but instead it hangs forever. Why?

Comment: Can you check the value of the `IsAsync` property of your NamedPipeServerStream?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The cancellation token is checked only if you're using an asynchronous namedpipe, which isn't the default (yup, the API is really poorly designed). To make it asynchronous, you have to provide the right value in `PipeOptions`:

```
NamedPipeServerStream server = new NamedPipeServerStream("aaqq", PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
var ct = new CancellationTokenSource();
ct.CancelAfter(1000);
server.WaitForConnectionAsync(ct.Token).Wait();
```

Then the cancellation token will work as expected.

Comment: On a side note: the same is true for file streams (which share I/O WinAPI calls with pipe streams) where asynchronicity also needs to be manually enabled.

Comment: It seems crazy the default behaviour is to silently hang. Maybe the `XAsync` methods should throw if the stream isnt async.

Comment: This solution seems to work. However, it only worked for me AFTER I restarted my machine. I guess something is cached by the OS the 1st time it is created and then changing the options to allow async operation is not honored until the pipe is re-created. Obviously, I used the same name.